# Можно ли в Java с помощью аннотаций убрать дублирования полей и сеттеров в статическом классе и его родительском классе?

Tags: java

В погоне за лаконичным, но при этом обязующим не забыть сделать необходимые действия синтаксисом реализовал билдер (паттерн для передачи большого количества параметров), позволяющий создавать объекты таким образом:

```
new Person(
  Person.specifyParameters(new Person.RequiredParameters() {
    @Override public void setID() { this.ID = "1"; }
    @Override public void setFamilyName() { this.familyName = "毛"; }
  })
    // и дальше опциональные параметры...
    .setGivenName("澤東")
    .setFamilyNameSpell("Мао")
    .setGivenNameSpell("Цзэдун")
);
```

Его преимущества:

1. Последовательность параметров не имеет значения.
2. Пользователь не может забыть, КАКИЕ параметры обязательны к инициализации, а какие - опциональные. Хотя, например, в `setID()` пользователь и может по невнимательности просеттить что-то вместо ID, он не может забыть про то, что надо реализовать метод `setID` -  иначе программа не скомпилируется.

Ну и ещё, не знаю, считать это достоинством или нет, класс в классе `Person` инкапсулирован билдер для своих же инстансов. Объективно пока не могу доказать, что это плохо, но мне как-то не хочется выносить билдер в отдельный класс.

Недостаток реализации - дублирование полей и сеттеров в классе `Person` и в его дочернем классе `ParametersObject`. Была бы возможность сослаться на собственный статический абстрактный класс, работы было бы меньше, а пока реализация такова:

```
package dev.example.BusinessRules.Entities;


public class Person {

  private String ID;
  private String familyName;
  private String familyNameSpell;
  private String givenName;
  private String givenNameSpell;


  public Person(ParametersObject parametersObject) {
    parametersObject.initializeSpecifiedFields(this);
  }

  public static ParametersObject specifyParameters(Person.RequiredParameters requiredParameters) {
    return new Person.ParametersObject(requiredParameters);
  }


  public String getID() { return this.ID; }

  public String getFamilyName() {
    return familyName;
  }
  public Person setFamilyName(String familyName) {
    this.familyName = familyName;
    return this;
  }

  public String getGivenName() { return givenName; }
  public Person setGivenName(String givenName) {
    this.givenName = givenName;
    return this;
  }

  public String getFamilyNameSpell() { return familyNameSpell; }
  public Person setFamilyNameSpell(String familyNameSpell) {
    this.familyNameSpell = familyNameSpell;
    return this;
  }

  public String getGivenNameSpell() {
    return givenNameSpell;
  }
  public Person setGivenNameSpell(String givenNameSpell) {
    this.givenNameSpell = givenNameSpell;
    return this;
  }

  public static class ParametersObject {

    private final String ID;
    private final String familyName;
    private String givenName;
    private String familyNameSpell;
    private String givenNameSpell;

    public ParametersObject(Person.RequiredParameters requiredParameters) {
      this.ID = requiredParameters.ID;
      this.familyName = requiredParameters.familyName;
    }

    public void initializeSpecifiedFields(Person person) {
      person.ID = this.ID;
      person.familyName = this.familyName;
      person.givenName = this.givenName;
      person.familyNameSpell = this.familyNameSpell;
      person.givenNameSpell = this.givenNameSpell;
    }

    public ParametersObject setGivenName(String givenName) { this.givenName = givenName; return this; }
    public ParametersObject setFamilyNameSpell(String familyNameSpell) { this.familyNameSpell = familyNameSpell; return this; }
    public ParametersObject setGivenNameSpell(String givenNameSpell) { this.givenNameSpell = givenNameSpell; return this; }
  }

  public static abstract class RequiredParameters {

    public String ID;
    public String familyName;

    public abstract void setID();
    public abstract void setFamilyName();
  }
}
```

Прочитав уроки по Java-аннотациям, в большинстве случаев так и не понял, что они конкретно делают и вообще не понял, КАК они это делают. Но вопрос такой: можно ли внутри `ParametersObject` уменьшить количество кода с помощью аннотаций? Убрать нужно в первую очередь дублирования полей и геттеров.

Цель всей этой акробатики - приблизится к лаконичному TypeScript-синтаксису. Вот как просто на TypeScript-е можно реализовать приведённую выше концепцию:

```
class Person {

  private ID;
  private familyName;
  private familyNameSpell?; // опциональный параметр
  private givenName?; // опциональный параметр
  private givenNameSpell?; // опциональный параметр

  public constructor(parametersObject: {
    ID: string; // обязательный параметр - без него программа не скомпилируется
    familyName: string; // обязательный параметр - без него программа не скомпилируется
    familyNameSpell?: string; // опциональный параметр
    givenName?: string; // опциональный параметр
    givenNameSpell?: string;
  }) {
    this.ID = parametersObject.ID;
    this.familyName = parametersObject.familyName;
    this.familyNameSpell = parametersObject.familyNameSpell;
    this.givenName = parametersObject.givenName;
    this.givenNameSpell = parametersObject.givenNameSpell;
  }
}

new Person({
  ID: "1",
  familyName: "毛", // если забыть обязательный параметр - TypeScript не скомпилируется
  familyNameSpell : "Мао",
  // ... опустил остальные опциональные параметры
})
```

### Вторая реализация

Поразмыслив, я пришел к выводу, что в `ParametersObject` указывать опциональные параметры не нужно - мы можем их настроить уже в самом инстансе `Person` через цепные сеттеры. После этого оказалось, что класс `ParametersObject` не нужен - нужен только `RequiredParameters`.

```java
public class Person {

  private String ID;
  private String familyName;
  private String familyNameSpell;
  private String givenName;
  private String givenNameSpell;


  public Person(RequiredParameters parametersObject) {
    this.ID = parametersObject.ID;
    this.familyName = parametersObject.familyName;
  }


  public String getID() { return this.ID; }

  public String getFamilyName() {
    return familyName;
  }
  public Person setFamilyName(String familyName) {
    this.familyName = familyName;
    return this;
  }

  public String getGivenName() { return givenName; }
  public Person setGivenName(String givenName) {
    this.givenName = givenName;
    return this;
  }

  public String getFamilyNameSpell() { return familyNameSpell; }
  public Person setFamilyNameSpell(String familyNameSpell) {
    this.familyNameSpell = familyNameSpell;
    return this;
  }

  public String getGivenNameSpell() {
    return givenNameSpell;
  }
  public Person setGivenNameSpell(String givenNameSpell) {
    this.givenNameSpell = givenNameSpell;
    return this;
  }

  public static abstract class RequiredParameters {

    public String ID;
    public String familyName;

    public abstract void setID();
    public abstract void setFamilyName();
  }
}
```

Теперь API стала немного лаконичнее:

```java
new Person(
  new Person.RequiredParameters() {
    public void setID() { this.ID = "1"; }
    public void setFamilyName() { this.familyName = "毛"; }
  }
)
    .setGivenName("澤東")
    .setFamilyNameSpell("Мао")
    .setGivenNameSpell("Цзэдун")
```

Comment: Вариант "в `Person` сделать конструктор с обязательными параметрами и завести сеттеры для опциональных параметров (или просто поля сделать публичными, чтобы не страдать с заведением сеттеров)" чем-то не подойдёт?

Comment: сделать можно все. вопрос в целесообразности. для меня сейчас единственный  целесообразный билдер - билдер из коробки от lombok. а писать такое количество кода для реализации билдера, тем более использовать кастомные аннотации, а, как следствие, рефлексию, не вижу смысла. слишком сложно для такой протой задачи. может при создании объектов с помощью такого билдера вы ошибок и не допустите, но в процессе реализации наиграетесь так, что мало не покажется: долго и сложно писать, тяжело тестить и дебажить. посему смысла не вижу

Comment: @Regent Благодарю Вас за комментарий. "Поля сделать публичными" - в классе Person однозначно нет, потому что это слишком важный класс, чтобы открывать его поля. В `Person.RequiredParameters` - можно. "в Person сделать конструктор с обязательными параметрами" - можно, при этом порядок аргументов/параметров/свойств не должен иметь значения.

Comment: @Дмитрий, Благодарю Вас за комментарий. "сделать можно все" - я не против бросить вызов Lombok, если Java позволяет реализовать билдер ещё изящнее. "а писать такое количество кода для реализации билдера, тем более использовать кастомные аннотации" - если с помощью аннотаций можно однотипный код вынести свою собственную библиотеку, то я это сделаю. А пока мне надо понять, как могут помочь аннотации при решении моей задачи.

Comment: @БоковГлеб 1. В `Person` предполагаются более сложные геттеры и сеттеры? Что в нём слишком важного? Потому что простые (как в вопросе) геттеры и сеттеры - на мой взгляд, переусложнение для обычной дата-модели. 2. Зачем нужен произвольный порядок аргументов? Стоит ли это того, чтобы сильно усложнять код?

Comment: основная мысль этого комментария на в том, что "сделать можно все", как вы решили. вы можете бросит вызов lombok, а можете сразу спрингу, чтобы не мелочиться. изобретать свои велосипеды даже иногда полезно. но когда закончите эту работу (если закончите ее успешно), обратите внимание, сколько раз в дальнейшем вам пригодится то, что вы написали. с очень высокой вероятностью никогда по указанным мной причинам. единственный плюс от всего этого - вы однозначно чему-то научитесь (хотя бы разберетесь с аннотациями). если вам все равно, что и зачем  писать, а цель - только научиться, то можно и так

Comment: @Regent, " В Person предполагаются более сложные геттеры и сеттеры?" - да. "Что в нём слишком важного?" - он, будучи сущностью бизес-логики, находится на самом верху иерархии зависимостей. Если позволить второстепенным модулям беспрепятственно менять поля критической сущности Person, то смысл тогда в инкапсуляции... "Зачем нужен произвольный порядок аргументов?" Вот, когда это критично. Например у нас среди аргументов идут подряд три строки: `(/*...*/, String familyName,  String familyNameSpell, String givenName)`. (Продолжение в следующем комментарии)

Comment: @Regent, Программист забыл, что идёт сначала: `familyNameSpell` или `givenName`, и в результате на месте `givenName` у нас `familyNameSpell` и наоборот. Потом, например, мы захотели в середину перечисления  большого количества аргументов добавить новый параметр и ещё переместить пару штук. Конструктор переписывать может и не придётся, а вот все команды, создающие объект - ещё как придётся.

Comment: @Дмитрий, "с очень высокой вероятностью никогда по указанным мной причинам" - если моё решение улучшить нельзя, то я вообще не буду его "ставить на вооружение". А пока мне нужно в этом вопросе узнать, как можно в Java улучшить моё решение, сделав его лаконичнее без потери функциональности.

Comment: @БоковГлеб ещё такой момент: `RequiredParameters` можно сделать интерфейсом, а его методы - get-методами. Пользователю не придётся думать, куда он должен присвоить значение в `void set` методе, а также будет чуть меньше шансов ошибиться, присвоив в методе значение не в то поле

Comment: @Regent, благодарю Вас за отличную идею! Введу её в оборот немедленно.